# How do i fix my delete method in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

Im very new to laravel and i've been trying to get my delete method to work for my todo list but it keeps showing me this error

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\TaskController::deleteRoute(), 1 passed in /opt/lampp/htdocs/toDoApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected
```

This is the function in my controller

```
public function deleteRoute(Task $task, $id) {
        
        $task = task::find($id);
 
        $task->delete();
 
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

this is my route

```
Route::delete('/deleteRoute', [TaskController::class, 'deleteRoute'])->name('deleteRoute');
```

This is my blade

```
<form action="{{ route('deleteRoute', $task->id) }}" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button type="submit">
                        <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-8 h-8 hover:text-red-500">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M14.74 9l-.346 9m-4.788 0L9.26 9m9.968-3.21c.342.052.682.107 1.022.166m-1.022-.165L18.16 19.673a2.25 2.25 0 01-2.244 2.077H8.084a2.25 2.25 0 01-2.244-2.077L4.772 5.79m14.456 0a48.108 48.108 0 00-3.478-.397m-12 .562c.34-.059.68-.114 1.022-.165m0 0a48.11 48.11 0 013.478-.397m7.5 0v-.916c0-1.18-.91-2.164-2.09-2.201a51.964 51.964 0 00-3.32 0c-1.18.037-2.09 1.022-2.09 2.201v.916m7.5 0a48.667 48.667 0 00-7.5 0" />
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </form>
```

ive tried just sending the id and switched to my Task $task with Request $request to see if theres any difference but no luck. the same error keeps popping up

Comment: `Task $task, $id` is unnecessary; pick one or the other (preferably the first, so you can skip the Task::find()` step. After that, you need to add the task parameter to your route, i.e. `Route::delete('/deleteRoute/{task}'`

Answer (score 0):

Change your route to

```
Route::delete('/deleteRoute/{task}', 
    [TaskController::class, 'deleteRoute'])->name('deleteRoute');
```

This `{task}` is generally the **ID (primry key)** of the entry that you are trying to delete.

```
  //Controller 

  public function deleteRoute(Task $task) {

      try {

        $task->delete();

        return redirect('/');

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

    return redirect()->withErrors(['msg' => 'The Error: '.$e->getMessage()]);

    }
```

**try....catch** will catch any exception that is thrown [any database error] and then you can retrieve in your view.

Comment: yeah i added the {task} to my route and removed my $id and it worked. after that, i tried adding the catch feature but i got this error on vs code 
```syntax error, unexpected token "catch", expecting "function" or "const"```